# An xcopy batch file does not run properly

Tags: xcopy

I'm trying to run an xcopy batch file, and can't get it to work.  While not my original intent, I'm trying to get it to copy the folders in a public documents directory to another folder.  I use it on other machines with no problem, but this one doesn't work.  What am I missing?

xcopy C:\users\Public\Public_Documents C:Copy /s /e /y /c

Comment: Is this on the same version of windows? Also, why not `C:\Copy` for the destination? `xcopy32`

Comment: Did it say any errors?

Answer (score -1):

The code should be formatted like this.

```
@echo off
    xcopy "C:\Users\Public\Documents" "C:\Copy\" /d /e /y
pause
EXIT
```